# call function in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, onmouseup

I am trying to call a function from a div like the following

```
<div id='div_abstract'>
 {content.abstract && content.abstract.length ? (
 <article id="abstract" onMouseUp={spanSelect}>{content.abstract </article>) : ''}
</div>
```

My functional component is structured like this

```
export default function ExternalInfos(props) {
 ...
function spanSelect() { ... }
 return(
  ...
 );
}
```

And the function I'm trying to call is

```
let table = [];
    function spanSelect() {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.setAttribute("id","span");
        if (window.getSelection()) {
          var text = window.getSelection();
          if (text.rangeCount) {
            var range = text.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            text.removeAllRanges();
            text.addRange(range);
          };
        };
        let object = window.getSelection().toString();
        table.push(object);
        const annotation = document.getElementById("annotationArea");
        annotation.updateObjectAnnotation(table);
      }
```

But nothing happens when I select text from my div and it doesn't return an error.
How do I solve this?

Comment: The capitalization is wrong. Needs to be `onMouseUp={span_select}`, not `onmouseup={span_select}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize the event handler prop: `onMouseUp`.

From the React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

"React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase."

Comment: I modified it but it still doesn't work, even using `onMouseUp={this.span_select}`

Comment: Remove `this`.  It should be `onMouseUp={span_select}`

Comment: I tried without `this` but it didn't work

Comment: In that case, you'll need to provide a more complete copy of your code to analyze. Please edit your question to include that.